How does Karkaroff know about Moody's old age paranoia?
Mad-Eye Moody was one of the best aurors as Charlie told Harry and he caught many death eaters during the first wizarding war. So he was sharp in the first wizarding war.

"Who is Mad-Eye?" asked Harry.
"He's retired, used to work at the Ministry," said Charlie. "I met him
once when Dad took me into work with him. He was an Auror - one of the
best...a Dark wizard catcher," he added, seeing Harry's blank look.
"Half the cells in Azkaban are full because of him.

But 14 years down the line, when he's not that sharp and is said to be little paranoid, says Charlie in the same conversation.

He made himself loads of enemies, though...the families of people he
caught, mainly...and I heard he's been getting really paranoid in his
old age. Doesn't trust anyone anymore. Sees Dark wizards everywhere.

However, Karkaroff was caught during or at the end of first wizarding war and made a deal with ministry and got off soon after and became a teacher in Durmstrang which is located somewhere in Scandinavia, far far from Britain or any news about Britain. But he has news about a very recent phenomenon about Moody.

"We all know Professor Moody considers the morning wasted if he hasn't
discovered six plots to murder him before lunchtime," said Karkaroff
loudly.

How is Karkaroff aware that Moody has become paranoid in recent years?

I don’t think there is any canon answer to this, but IRL people in specialized fields have friends that will keep them up to date on others in the field, even when separated by distance. I would imagine the same of the HP world. There is no reason that gossip of Moody wouldn’t reach Karkaroff.

The question seems to be premised on "far far from Britain or any news about Britain". Is there evidence to support this premise (particularly the latter half)?

You have pretty much answered your own question:

"He made himself loads of enemies, though...the families of people he caught, mainly...and I heard he's been getting really paranoid in his old age. Doesn't trust anyone anymore. Sees Dark wizards everywhere."

Like the muggle world, the wizarding world has gossip that passes through the mouths of many. Not only that, but Moody is a famous auror. He is one of the best - it would be surprising that Karkaroff isn't aware of Moody. After all, Karkaroff is a Death Eater. Additionally, the fact that he's getting paranoid in old age doesn't mean it's a very recent event. This means that there is even more time for news of Moody's paranoia to reach him.
Not only that but there was also news about Moody freaking out about some intruder and moving dustbins around. The Daily Prophet circulates around the wizarding world along with gossip. Even if Karkaroff hadn't heard Moody's paranoia from gossip, there is a high chance that he would've learned about it from the news or gossip from the news.
